# Change Widget Constructor in UI

Tags: qt, user-interface, widget

I ran into a problem with Qt while promoting my QGLWidget for the GUI.
Since the constructor of my QGLWidget is

```
GLWidget::GLWidget( const QGLFormat& format, QWidget* parent )
: QGLWidget( format, parent ),
  m_vertexBuffer( QGLBuffer::VertexBuffer ) {}
```

So the object should get instantiated like this

```
QGLFormat glFormat;
glFormat.setVersion( 3, 3 );
glFormat.setProfile( QGLFormat::CoreProfile );
glFormat.setSampleBuffers( true );
GLWidget w( glFormat, parent );
```

But the ui_mainwindow.h does this automatically with

```
widget = new GLWidget(centralWidget);
```

which can't be modified due to the fact that the ui_mainwindow.h is created new every time the UI is recompiled. So I will probably have to tell in my maindwindow.cpp that the GLWidget is to be instantiated different from the standard constructor, but with a QFormat. Any idea how this is done?

Comment: Can't you simply call `widget->setFormat(format)` afterwards?

Comment: [void setFormat(const QGLFormat & format)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qglwidget-obsolete.html) is obsolete and shouldn't be used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can not be achieved using the Qt Designer auto-generated code.

There are atleast two different kind of solutions for this:

- Subclass QGLWidget to set the QGLFormat in its MyGLWidget(QWidget* parent = 0); constructor.

or

- Create the widget manually (without Qt Designer).

I prefer the latter one because I like to be in control.